# 'File not found' error on an existing file

Tags: asp-classic

I have sometimes a 'file not found' error on the 'DeleteFile' line of this small script:
(I guess when several clients open the script as the same time)

```
if objFSO.FileExists(fileName) then
    Set f = objFSO.GetFile(fileName)
    if DateDiff("d", f.DateLastModified, date()) > 3 then
        Application.Lock
        objFSO.DeleteFile(fileName)
        Application.Unlock
    end if
    Set f = nothing
end if
```

But this should be protected by the 'FileExists' on the first line?
Any idea ?  Thanks.

Comment: What is with the `Application.Lock` and `Application.Unlock` statements? Your not doing anything with Application variables in your code so they are pointless??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a race condition.  The file attributes are cached in the second line with `GetFile`.  If the file exists at that point, the code will continue to run.  You either need to lock before that point, or refresh your attribute cache and double-check existence after `Application.Lock`.

Comment: Seems like you could wrap your if statement with the locks instead of imbedding them inside the if statement.

Comment: @Dee The "locks" are pointless as there is no Application variables being manipulated. Having them there does nothing and will **not** stop the behaviour the OP is experiencing.

Comment: @Chrigou Remove the `Application.Lock` and `Application.Unlock` they are doing nothing just bloating your code.

Comment: @Lankymart I thought wrongly that the script was locked to not have a race condition. But what about writing a file in a web server? Can I expect garbage in my files if many users load the same script?